# Are there any books on Rav Papa

Tags: talmud-gemara, babylonian-exile

Are there any books on Rav Papa? I've been searching but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/6795 h/t https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%A4%D7%A4%D7%90#%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%94_%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%AA